# conversion const object reference to const object

Tags: c++

I recently learned that

```
Object const & object();

Object o = object();
```

would cause a copy. So I am curious as to what happens when

```
Object const o = object();
```

will do.

Comment: The first is a function declaration.

Comment: Worst naming convention ever...

Comment: @David I think it's supposed to be. But it messed with my head too.

Comment: Keen observation, @David ;-) It's to provide you with a context, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll also make a copy.

To avoid a copy, you can create a *reference* that is bound to the same object as the reference that the function returns:

```
Object const & o = object();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also copy, your `o` should be constructed as long as it's an object. Copy-constructed here.

Answer (score 0):

References are not object but they are just an alias so assigning a reference is same as assigning an object.

```
Object const & object();

Object o = object();   //here o is not constant. you can do o=object() again.

Object const o = object();  //here o is constant. you can't do o=object() again after its initialization.
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't know whether `Object` is a class that has a constant assignment operator. It'd be silly, but possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB right .The title is really misleading. i'm just assumed the object as class. +1 from my side. your ans is accepted without upvote. strange.